# why operation not permitted when kill a nonexistent process and why need to be killed with sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, process, sudo, kill

Linux version: **CentOS 7**

```
[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$ll apis_response_time_analysis.pid 
-rw-r--r-- 1 weizhong users 5 Jan 22 09:40 apis_response_time_analysis.pid

[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$cat apis_response_time_analysis.pid 
20795

[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$sudo ps -ef | grep 20795
weizhon+ 24876  9196  0 11:41 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 20795
```

I can't find the PID, then I've tried to kill it by my account.
However, it saied **Operation not permitted** instead of **No such process**

```
[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$kill -9 20795
-bash: kill: (20795) - Operation not permitted

[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$kill -9 20795123   <--- a pid not exists
-bash: kill: (20795123) - No such process
```

then I tried to kill it with `sudo`, I've executed

```
[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$sudo kill 20795    <-- no output

[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$sudo kill -9 20795
kill: sending signal to 20795 failed: No such process
```

Then I executed by my account again

```
[weizhong@bja /tmp]
$kill 20795
-bash: kill: (20795) - No such process
```

I'm sure that pid 20795 is generated by my account. Currently I can't find 20795, but when I kill it, return `Operation not permitted` instead of `No such process`, I wanna know why, and why my process need to be killed by sudo

Comment: In Ubuntu `ps -ef` gives the same listing regardless of `sudo`. It looks like PID 20795 was free at the time you performed the `grep`, but was then allocated to another process. Or it could have been a thread ID, but I don't know what `kill` does with TIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the owner of the process you are trying to kill. This is the reason for both `ps` output — which did not list process 20795 (see @kamil-maciorowski answer) — and the `sudo` requirement to kill 20795.

You can use [`ps aux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to list all processes including those you don't own. You can also use `-p` argument to show a specific process which best fit your need:

```
ps -up 20795
```

You will see something like this:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
foo      20795  0.0  0.0  14728  1888 tty3     Ss+  12:03   0:00 bar
```

My guess is that user will be root (elevated privileges) or maybe another specific system user.
You then need `sudo` to kill a process you don't own. And you succeed to kill it. The empty answer for `sudo kill 20795` tells it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Notice your `ps -ef | grep 20795` returned the `grep` itself only – the match was with the command line, not the `PID`. There was no process with the `PID` you specified.

My guess is the number may have been incorrect. It probably matched somebody else's thread ID and this way `sudo kill` killed somebody else's entire process which was not what you wanted.